# How to convert HEX to human readable

Tags: node.js, hex, ascii

I'm trying to convert from a HEX to ASCII and I'm getting this message. I would like to understand how to interpret it in the correct way.

```
0x2b6162630704fe17
```

Using the npm module [hex2ascii](https://npm.runkit.com/hex2ascii) it returns this:

```
"+abc\u0007\u0004þ\u0017"
```

if I convert from an [online converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html), it returns :

```
+abcþ
```

Could someone help me to interpret this? I am using node.

Am I doing something wrong?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: `"2b6162630704fe17".match (/(..)/g).reduce ((a,c) => a + String.fromCharCode(parseInt (c,16)), "") //"+abcþ"`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the string in the console, you will notice that the two strings you're posted are actually the same.

The gist is, the string contains nonprintable unicode characters, which get escaped by the hex2ascii module.

The online converter you are using tries to display those characters. Since they are not printable you simply cannot see them.

Let's convert the hex string

```
var conv = "2b6162630704fe17".match (/(..)/g).reduce ((a,c) => a + String.fromCharCode(parseInt (c,16)), "") 
conv //"+abcþ"
```

It looks just like the String from the converter! Let's compare it to the other string

```
conv === "+abc\u0007\u0004þ\u0017" // true
```

Comment: Got it, but how should I interpret this `þ` sign?

Comment: Interpret it as what? Where did you get it from? What do you want to do with that? It‘s your data, you should know what you want to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its 8 digit ASCII?

If it is, each 2 hex characters represents a given ASCII number.

So:
   2b6162630704fe17

- First 2b, which is 2 * 16 + 11 = 43 - which is a plus sign
- 61, which is 6 * 16 + 1 = 97 = lowercase a
- 62, which is 6 * 16 + 2 = 98 = lowercase b
- 63, which is 6 * 16 + 3 = 99 = lowercase c
- 07, which is 0 * 16 + 7 = 7 = that's a special unprintable character.

references to convert the numbers to characters - asciitable.com

Based on the 07, I wonder if your data is truly ascii, or a different encoding.

Comment: I'm actually not sure of which format. The device sends me reports in HEX. Its doc says it is using the ASCII format and I couldn't interpret it like that.